# Checking a string value to return a range from another worksheet then add to .To line in email

Tags: excel, vba, string, email, outlook

I am trying to get email addresses from a worksheet(Sheet1) into the .To line for an outlook email based on the specific string value in the main worksheet.

I have managed to play with it several ways but none have given the results I need. The idea is that it checks a cell on the main worksheet for a specific string value, then would reference a specific range of cells in one column from another worksheet based on the string value and include these emails in the .To line, separated by a";".

I also noticed it removed data from the cells when it pulled it in testing, replacing some cells with "Column1"

```
   Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim emailRng As Range, cl As Range
    Dim sTo As String

  Set emailRng = Worksheets("SHEET1").Range("D3:D20")
    
    For Each cl In emailRng
        sTo = sTo & ";" & cl.Value
    Next
    
    sTo = Mid(sTo, 2)
   
    If InStr(ActiveCell.Value, "ABC") > 0 Then
        emailRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET1").Range("D3:D5")
           
    ElseIf InStr(ActiveCell.Value, "XYZ") > 0 Then
        emailRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET1").Range("D11:D15")
          
    End If

    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Select Case Target.Column
        Case Is = 15
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            With OutMail
                .To = sTo
                .CC = "REQ@EMAIL.COM"
                .Subject = ""
                .HTMLBody = "Please attend "
                .Display
            End With
    End Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, creating a new Outlook Application instance in the `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` handler is not really a good idea. Consider creating an Outlook instance once and then only create a new email in the event handler instead.

Instead of relying on To or CC properties:

```
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
With OutMail
   .To = sTo
   .CC = "REQ@EMAIL.COM"
   .Subject = ""
   .HTMLBody = "Please attend "
   .Display
End With
```

I'd recommend using the [Recipients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.recipients) property of the `MailItem` class which returns a `Recipients` collection that represents all the recipients for the Outlook item. For example:

```
Sub CreateStatusReportToBoss() 
 Dim myItem As Outlook.MailItem
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 
 
 Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
 Set myRecipient = myItem.Recipients.Add("Eugene Astafiev") 
 myItem.Subject = "Status Report" 
 myItem.Display 
End Sub
```

Then I'd recommend using the `Resolve` or [ResolveAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients.resolveall) method which attempts to resolve all the `Recipient` objects in the `Recipients` collection against the Address Book.

```
Sub CheckRecipients() 
 Dim MyItem As Outlook.MailItem 
 Dim myRecipients As Outlook.Recipients 
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 
 
 Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
 Set myRecipients = myItem.Recipients 
 myRecipients.Add("Eugene Astafiev") 
 myRecipients.Add("Dmitry Anafriev") 
 myRecipients.Add("Tom Wilon") 
 If Not myRecipients.ResolveAll Then 
   For Each myRecipient In myRecipients 
     If Not myRecipient.Resolved Then 
       MsgBox myRecipient.Name 
     End If 
   Next 
 End If 
End Sub
```

You may find the [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/) article helpful.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback!

My question I suppose is why would the current method be so bad? I almost have it doing everything I need (this is a short term solution - another project is in the works) aside from retrieving the emails in a particular cell on another worksheet that is already set up. Currently if I double click the cell I need to, it generates the email properly with everything but the proper recipients. I am more so looking for help purely for the purpose of checking the value of one cell in one workbook and getting a range of recipients in another.